# Login doesn't work but doesn't give any error

Tags: php

I cannot log in to my web-app, I'm inserting right combinations but it only displays "Sorry, those credentials do not match" message.

```html
<?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
 header("Location: /");
}

require 'database.php';

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
 
 $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, policajt_id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username');
 $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
 $records->execute();
 $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $message = '';

 if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password']) ){

  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
  header("Location: /");

 } else {
  $message = 'Sorry, those credentials do not match';
 }

endif;

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Two things. I guess to check if `password_verify` runs. Do that by taking it out of the if. It returns a `boolean`. So `echo` that. [And try a `try/catch` on the code from `$results` on.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: `count($results) > 0` should just be `$results`. `fetch` returns `false` when there's no row, and `count(false)` is `1`.